# Angular 7 & Angular Material - Validator not showing MinLength error

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

I am working with Angular 7 and Angular Material and there is a small problem with my code that i can't solve. The next piece of code should return a string with my message error if there is one:

```js
    getPasswordErrorMessage() {
        return this.passwordFormControl.hasError('required') ? 'Password is required' :
              this.passwordFormControl.hasError('minLength') ? 'Password must be at least 6 characters long' : '';
    }
```

And it should be display between the `mat-error` tags:

```html
    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput minlenght="6" type="password" placeholder="Password" [formControl]="passwordFormControl" [errorStateMatcher]="matcher">
        <mat-error *ngIf="passwordFormControl.invalid">
             {{ getPasswordErrorMessage() }}
        </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
```

Either way, only the "required field" error is being display. Is there a reason for the minLength error not to be displayed?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of how you set up the function for returning error. The ternary will return the first match, and don't care about the next one.

```
getPasswordErrorMessage() {
   let error = '';
   error = this.passwordFormControl.hasError('required') ? 'Password is required' : '';
   error = this.passwordFormControl.hasError('minLength') && error ? `${error}   * 
  Password must be at least 6 characters long` : this.passwordFormControl.hasError('minLength') ? 'Password must be at least 6 characters long' : ''; 
 return error;
  }
```

This should do the trick.